# How to understand the larger than $g$ acceleration of the free end of a falling chain?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, string

[In this article](https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/7/1/045) I read that the acceleration of the free end of a falling folded chain is greater than $g$, but I cannot really understand why. Why isn´t the acceleration just $g$ since it is a free fall? Can I explain this with some simple equations?

Answer (score 2):

Mungan offers an accessible interpretation in "[Newtonian analysis of a folded chain drop](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Carl-Mungan/publication/324605977_Newtonian_analysis_of_a_folded_chain_drop/links/5ad8ed2c0f7e9b28593c9c09/Newtonian-Analysis-of-a-Folded-Chain-Drop.pdf)":

"*Think of [the] bottom link as a small
grappling hook connected to [the now-motionless section] by a very stiff elastic
band. To go around the corner, that band must stretch slightly, thereby slowing down the hook. Just as the hook comes to rest, it attaches without dissipation to [the still-moving section]. The elastic potential energy in the band now pulls on and speeds up the rest of the falling chain, giving it extra kinetic energy.*"

As Mungan notes, the key aspect of analyzing the problem is that minimal energy is converted into heat—in stark contrast with the scenario of dropping a loose chain on a surface. (One might assume this statement, deduce it, or observe it.) From this starting point one can conclude that all kinetic energy is transferred to the still-dropping section of the chain, which, if it were continuous, would speed up without limit.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the free body diagram of the top link of the chain. That link has its own weight, and there is a tension in the chain due to all the links beneath the top link. The acceleration must therefore be $>g$

There is tension because, before the chain was dropped, it was held up, and to hold the bottom chain stationary, the top chain must pull upward on the whole bottom chain with a tension equal to the weight of the bottom chain.

Now, you just started dropping the chain, so the tension is yet to have dissipated. The bottom does not fall until the top reaches where the bottom is, and so the top must keep holding the bottom up, and that means the tension must keep being there, and the top must keep accelerating $>g$

Watch this covered in early episodes of Veritasium (and he has so many of these slinky drop videos) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKb2tCtpvNU

Answer (score 1):

Assume mathematical pendulum length L mass m.

the position vector to the mass is:

$$\mathbf R= L\,\begin{bmatrix}
   \sin\phi) \\
   \cos(\phi) \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

from here the acceleration $~a_y~$

$$ a_y=L\sin \left( \phi  \right) \ddot\phi +L\cos \left( \phi 
 \right) {\dot\phi }^{2}
$$

and with the equation of motion

$$ \ddot\phi=-\frac gL\,\sin(\phi)$$

$$a_y=- \left( \sin \left( \phi  \right)  \right) ^{2}g+L\cos \left( 
\phi  \right) {\dot\phi }^{2}
$$

thus $ |a_y| > g ~$   is depending on the pendulum angular velocity  $~\dot\phi (t)~$ and the initial condition  $~\dot\phi (0)~$

**Numerical result**

with the initial condition $~\phi(0)=\pi/2~,\dot\phi (0)=0~$
and $~L=1~g=10~$ you obtain

[image]